# Installation of npm module artillery

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, npm-install

When I run `sudo npm install -g artillery` it gives the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/home/newgen/.npm-global/bin/artillery -> /home/newgen/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/artillery/bin/artillery
/home/newgen/.npm-global/lib
`-- artillery@1.6.0-2
```

Then if I run `artillery` it shows:

```
artillery: command not found
```

How do I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `npm i artillery@1.6.0-2 -S`. This way you're specifying npm to install the artillery's latest release.

Comment: its still not working, showing the same error. kindly help